# How can I enable containerization on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, docker, kubernetes, containers

I would like to deploy our microservices on a Windows Server 2012 installed machine. How can I enable containerization on that machine? On the Internet, the technical guides generally folds in two favors. One is for container technology on Linux platforms and the other one is for the Azure. I could not find any specific guide for what I am trying for.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Docker is not supported on Windows Server 2012, see [Docker Forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/windows-server-2012-r2/24267) or [Docker on Windows Server](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows-server).

You will need at least Windows Server 2016.